# Llamar a otro .java

Tags: java, maven

estoy intentando crear un bot de discord con java maven y me gustaria tener el nucleo separado de los comandos, y que el nucleo llame(inicie) a los comandos para que se puedan usar, he intentado llamarlo de la siguiente manera pero no funciona, me da un error de java.lang.NullPoinerException agradeceria que alguien me ayude:

EL NUCLEO

```
package darkdragon.team.dragonoid;

import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Game;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class App extends ListenerAdapter
{
    public static JDA api;
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        api = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(Ref.token).buildBlocking();
        api.addEventListener(new App());
        api.getPresence().setGame(Game.playing("MANTENIMIENTO"));
        MessageReceivedEvent evt = null;
        Commands.processCommand(evt);
    }

}
```

LOS COMANDOS

```
package darkdragon.team.dragonoid;

import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.MessageChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.User;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {
    public static void processCommand(MessageReceivedEvent evt) {
        User objUser = evt.getAuthor();
        Message objMsg = evt.getMessage();
        MessageChannel objMsgCh = evt.getChannel();
        String[] command = objMsg.getContentRaw().toLowerCase().replaceFirst(Ref.prefix, "").split(" ");
        if(command[0].equals("ping")) {
            objMsgCh.sendMessage(objUser.getAsMention() + "Pong!");
        }
    }
}
```

SALTA EL ERROR

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ¿De casualidad arroja un `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Si, me salta un java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: No creo, porque lo mio se trata de llamar a otro archivo en maven JDA

Comment: da lo mismo que framework o que biblioteca estes usando un error nullPointer solo tiene una explicacion y en tu codigo el error es evidente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nucleo como tal no esta inicializando el evento correctamente, se está enviando en null

```
MessageReceivedEvent evt = null;
Commands.processCommand(evt);
```

Por lo tanto en la primera linea que trate se utilizarse la información del evento se producira un NullPointerException

```
 User objUser = evt.getAuthor();
```

Comment: No entiendo, es esto una respuesta de solucion? Aun asi gracias supongo, voy a ver si puedo hacer algo a base de esto

Comment: @user9451723 estás buscando una causa del nullPointerException, te estoy exponiendo una, esto no quiere decir que sea la solución completa a lo que quieres implementar, no creo que alguien te de tal respuesta, pero si te ayudará a recordar por que se presentan los NullPointerExceptions

Comment: Si, supongo que me esta ayudando ya que estoy buscando la manera de no llamarlo con null, pero de momento no encuentro como llamarlo correctamente